# What affects the period and the frequency of a longitudinal vibration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, vibrations

In a lab experiment, our objective is to observe the characteristics of longitudinal waves/vibrations. If we changed the mass and amplitude, I feel that they either affect the period and frequency of the longitudinal spring (the spring is what was used), or our data is completely off the charts in terms of accuracy.

I know that the only factor that can change period/frequency for a *transverse* vibration is the length of the string (and acceleration due to gravity, of course), however is this the same for longitudinal vibrations as well?

My question is relatively broad but most likely it has a simple answer:
What are all the factors that change the frequency/period for a longitudinal vibration?

Comment: In principle, for linear oscillations, the period should be independent of the mass and amplitude...but in real life, most oscillations are nonlinear, especially at too high of an amplitude.  They are only approximately linear in the low-amplitude limit.  Maybe that's affecting your data.

Comment: Why should the frequency be independent of the mass on the system? The formula for the eigenfrequency of a mass-spring system predicts that the frequency is inverse proportional to the square root of the mass. The same relationship applies to waves in linear media: the density of the medium changes the frequency  (of modes). As long as the system is linear, the frequency should be independent of the amplitude. If you are observing variations, then you have either made a measurement error or you are already in the non-linear regime.

Comment: @CuriousOne so what you're saying is, mass does affect longitudinal vibrations?

Comment: @NathanReed our data only used amplitudes of 3cm and 6cm so it wasn't a large-scale thing.

Comment: The conventional wisdom of theoretical and experimental physics is that in an elastic system with coupled masses the resonance frequencies do depend on the masses and mass densities. :-) 
@NathanReed: 3cm compared to what? I have a couple of springs in my drawers for which elongation by 3cm would be a completely destructive.

Comment: @CuriousOne You're right; I was thinking of a pendulum, in which case the mass doesn't matter.  For mass-spring systems of course the ratio of mass and spring constant is what matters.